# Apex Test Results in Eclipse not reporting correctly

Tags: unit-test, eclipse, ide, failing-tests, force.com-ide

I'm using (the apparent latest because there's no updates ATM)

- Eclipse Neon v4.6.3
- Force.com IDE v38.0

When I run my Apex unit tests, I only get a green checkbox in a single item in the test results window, even when there are failing tests.

[image]

I do get the test coverage results.

Is this some sort of known bug or configuration issue?

Comment: What are your settings for download debug logs and for your individual logging settings for Apex Code, Workflow, etc? What you see would depend on those settings.

Comment: @crmprogdev where are those settings set? i think it worked in older versions...

Comment: oh i found it @crmprogdev most everything is Debug. Some are info. i hadn't configured those.

Comment: If that's the case, all you'll see are debug statements and Warnings.

Comment: @crmprogdev what should i set it to do get my test results? it seems a bit odd to adjust the tracing for a common *dev tool*

Comment: You'll need to be on Fine or Finer to see any details for your Apex Code. I recommend you read the Help Info on using the Developer Console which covers this info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56924/discussion-between-daniel-a-white-and-crmprogdev).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation couple of times. I don't know where is error, but I was helped by full synchronization of my IDE with my sandbox.

Right click on SRC folder in Eclipse -> Force.com -> Synchronize with server

We shouldn't have here any discrepancy between the environments.
[image]

Sometime you can see that not exist any real differences between local file and server file, but SalesForce say you that they exist. It's a bug. You just do right click on the file/folder and choose the "Save to Server"